# Group json data array by month

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have been trying to take the json data outputted from the database and create an new array that groups the data by month and year.

The problem is my new array doesn't output in the format that i need so i need to add the month and year but can't get the month grouping to work first. I think that might be right and resolve my issue, but I need help as arrays are confusing.

I have a codepen demo https://codepen.io/james182/pen/yLaqybP

```js
var data = [
  { name: "First", timestampSent: "Wed, 25 Nov 2020 - 11:01 AM" },
  { name: "Second", timestampSent: "Wed, 25 Nov 2020 - 11:21 AM" },
  { name: "Third", timestampSent: "Thu, 26 Nov 2020 - 10:21 AM" },
  { name: "Fourth", timestampSent: "Fri, 27 Nov 2020 - 13:52 PM" },
  { name: "Fifth", timestampSent: "Tue, 24 Dec 2020 - 11:01 AM" },
  { name: "Sixth", timestampSent: "Wed, 25 Dec 2020 - 01:01 AM" }
];

// Clear console before running
console.clear();

var list = [];
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  var dates = data[i].timestampSent.slice(5, 16);
  var mth = data[i].timestampSent.split(" ")[2];

  if (!list[mth]) {
    list[mth] = [];
  }

  list[mth].push({ name: data[i].name, date: data[i].timestampSent });

  console.log(mth);
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(list));
//console.log('list', list);

/*
outcome:
[{
'Nov': [
      {
        'name': 'First',
        'timestampSent': 'Wed, 25 Nov 2020 - 11:01 AM'
      },
      {
        'name': 'Second',
        'timestampSent': 'Wed, 25 Nov 2020 - 11:21 AM'
      },
      {
        'name': 'Third',
        'timestampSent': 'Thu, 26 Nov 2020 - 10:21 AM'
      },
      {
        'name': 'Fourth',
        'timestampSent': 'Fri, 27 Nov 2020 - 13:52 PM'
      }
    ],
    'Dec': [
      {
        'name': 'Fifth',
        'timestampSent': 'Tue, 24 Dec 2020 - 11:01 AM'
      },
      {
        'name': 'Sixth',
        'timestampSent': 'Wed, 25 Dec 2020 - 01:01 AM'
      }
    ]
  }]
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `list` should not be an array. Since you are using the month name ('Nov', 'Dec') as keys you should use an object.

```
var list = {};
```

Answer (score 0):

try change the line

```
list = []
```

to

```
list = {}
```

You will be using an object, not a list.
[Try it here](https://repl.it/join/ctemaxon-bokomoko)

Comment: Great and how would i add the year? year > month > data ie. {2021:[{ Jan: [{...},{...}] }

Comment: Trying to add the year > month > data   
var list = {}
// loop through all the data
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) 
{
  var dates = data[i].timestampSent.slice(5, 16);
  var mth = data[i].timestampSent.split(" ")[2];
  var year = data[i].timestampSent.split(" ")[3];
  
  // Push data into month Object
  if (!list[mth]) {
    list[mth] = [];
  }
  list[mth].push({ name: data[i].name, date: dates });
  
  //put months to years
  if (!list[year]) {
    list[year] = {};
  }
  list[year] = list[mth];
}